# PHP array data to be printed in HTML Table

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I have an array, which includes record set generated by codeigniter model.

I tried to print those records into a HTML table using my view. My view as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fuel Order:</title>
</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
<body>
<div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered"  style="font-size: 11px; ">
<tbody>
<?php
    if (!empty($printData)) {
        foreach ($printData as $item) {
?>
            <tr>        
                <td><p style="position: absolute;top: 20cm;right: 14cm"><?=$item->item_name?></p></td>
                <td><p style="position: absolute;top: 20cm;right: 11.5cm"><?=$item->fuel_qty?> Litres</p></td>
                <td><p style="position: absolute;top: 20cm;right: 6.5cm"><?=$this->amount_word?></p></td>                           
            </tr>           
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<?php   
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The view is working fine, except the records overprint each other.

Comment: Do you mean all records are printing, they're just all displaying at the same place on the page?  If so then `position: absolute;` is likely to blame.  What are you trying to accomplish with that?  Normally tables are just tables, you let them flow in the document as normal.

Comment: @David. You are correct. They're just all displaying at the same place on the page

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: Next time please post PURE HTML and CSS. This is NOT a PHP problem at all

Comment: If you have more than one record you need to vary the top: by the height of the set of values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have more than one record you need to vary the top: by the height of the set of values or height of preprinted grid

Also make sure the loop is closed BEFORE the `</tbody>`

```
<table class="table table-bordered"  style="font-size: 11px; ">
<tbody>
<?php
if (!empty($printData)) {
  $offset=2; // cm
  $cnt=0;
  foreach ($printData as $item) {
?>
<tr>        
  <td><p style="position: absolute;top: <?= ($cnt*$offset)+20 ?>cm;right: 14cm"><?=$item->item_name?></p></td>
  <td><p style="position: absolute;top: <?= ($cnt*$offset)+20 ?>cm;right: 11.5cm"><?=$item->fuel_qty?> Litres</p></td>
  <td><p style="position: absolute;top: <?= ($cnt*$offset)+20 ?>cm;right: 6.5cm"><?=$this->amount_word?></p></td>                           
</tr> 
<? $cnt++; 
  } // close your foreach HERE
  ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the style attributes from the `<p>` tags; they can't all have identical positions.

Set the position of the table, instead.

Comment: But I need to print that data at the specific place in a pre-printed form

Comment: I have updated the answer; position the top of the table instead, so rows will flow below.

Comment: No outs the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should close your **foreach** loop inside the table, but currently you closed it outside of it. Also put your if statement before *table* tag and ... (you have 2 *body* tag here!). It is better to use your *statements* like codes below (With **:** character to not been confused), remove `position: absolute` because it make your element(s) to have new coordinates according to the parent with non static position (If you need to move it set `position: relative` to them because it move your element according to its parent). As conclusion:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fuel Order:</title>
</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
<div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
    <?php if (!empty($printData)): ?>
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size: 11px;">
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($printData as $item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><p><?= $item->item_name ?></p></td>
                    <td><p><?= $item->fuel_qty ?> Litres</p></td>
                    <td><p><?= $this->amount_word ?></p></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: But I want to print these data into a static places on a pre-printed form, that uses a specific position. style="position: absolute;top: 20cm; is the correct top position.